# Update not working properly in Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have written an Oracle procedure if count is greater than 0 then update the table, but what is happening is it's updating all the records of the table with that one record.

Here is the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO T_CNT_1 FROM IPCOLO_BILLING_MASTER WHERE SAP_ID = P_SAP_ID;
        IF T_CNT_1 > 0 THEN
        
                UPDATE IPCOLO_BILLING_MASTER t1
   SET (ID                                      ,
    CMP                                     ,
    SAP_ID                                  ,
    ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE                       ,
    ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE                       ,
    RRH_COUNTCHANGE                         ,
    RRH_CHANGEDDATE                         ,
    TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE                     ,
    TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE                     ,
    RFS_DATE                                ,
    RFE1_DATE                               ,
    INFRA_PROVIDER                          ,
    IP_COLO_SITEID                          ,
    SITE_NAME                               ,
    R4GSTATE                                ,
    MW_INSTALLED                            ,
    DG_NONDG                                ,
    EB_NONEB                                ,
    TOWER_TYPE                              ,
    VENDOR_CODE                             ,
    RFCDATE                                 ,
    POLITICAL_STATE_NAME                    ,
    POLITICAL_STATE_CODE                    ,
    SITE_DROP_DATE                          ,
    CITY_NAME                               ,
    NEID                                    ,
    FACILITY_LATITUDE                       ,
    FACILITY_LONGITUDE                      ,
    RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE                       ,
    RJ_JC_NAME                              ,
    RJ_JC_CODE                              ,
    COMPANY_CODE                            ,
    BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_MASTER                 ,
    BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_MASTER                ,
    SITE_ADDRESS                            ,
    BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_INCREMENTAL            ,
    BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_INCREMENTAL           ,
    CREATED_BY                              ,
    CREATED_DATE                            ,
    SEL_CHANGED_VAL                         ,
    CMM                                     ,
    FCA                                     ,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY                         ,
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE                       ,
    IS_AUTO_UPDATED                         ,
    INITIATED_MANUAL_UPLOAD                 ,
    RFS_DATE_5G                             ,
    DROP_DATE_5G                            ,
    OLT_COUNT                               ,
    OLT_CHANGE_DATE                         ,
    DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES                 ,
    OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MINUTES            ,
    DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY                  ,
    OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MIN_MY             ,
    BK_RESPONSE_DATE                        ,
    IS5GPRESENT) = (SELECT t2.ID                                        ,
t2.CMP                                     ,
t2.SAP_ID                                  ,
t2.ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE                       ,
t2.ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE                       ,
t2.RRH_COUNTCHANGE                         ,
t2.RRH_CHANGEDDATE                         ,
t2.TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE                     ,
t2.TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE                     ,
t2.RFS_DATE                                ,
t2.RFE1_DATE                               ,
t2.INFRA_PROVIDER                          ,
t2.IP_COLO_SITEID                          ,
t2.SITE_NAME                               ,
t2.R4GSTATE                                ,
t2.MW_INSTALLED                            ,
t2.DG_NONDG                                ,
t2.EB_NONEB                                ,
t2.TOWER_TYPE                              ,
t2.VENDOR_CODE                             ,
t2.RFCDATE                                 ,
t2.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME                    ,
t2.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE                    ,
t2.SITE_DROP_DATE                          ,
t2.CITY_NAME                               ,
t2.NEID                                    ,
t2.FACILITY_LATITUDE                       ,
t2.FACILITY_LONGITUDE                      ,
t2.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE                       ,
t2.RJ_JC_NAME                              ,
t2.RJ_JC_CODE                              ,
t2.COMPANY_CODE                            ,
t2.BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_MASTER                 ,
t2.BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_MASTER                ,
t2.SITE_ADDRESS                            ,
t2.BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_INCREMENTAL            ,
t2.BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_INCREMENTAL           ,
t2.CREATED_BY                              ,
t2.CREATED_DATE                            ,
t2.SEL_CHANGED_VAL                         ,
t2.CMM                                     ,
t2.FCA                                     ,
t2.LAST_UPDATED_BY                         ,
SYSDATE,
--t2.LAST_UPDATED_DATE                       ,
t2.IS_AUTO_UPDATED                         ,
t2.INITIATED_MANUAL_UPLOAD                 ,
t2.RFS_DATE_5G                             ,
t2.DROP_DATE_5G                         ,
t2.OLT_COUNT                               ,
t2.OLT_CHANGE_DATE                         ,
t2.DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MINUTES                 ,
t2.OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MINUTES            ,
t2.DIESEL_DOWNTIME_MIN_MY                  ,
t2.OVERALL_INFRA_OUTAGE_MIN_MY             ,
t2.BK_RESPONSE_DATE                     ,
t2.IS5GPRESENT
                         FROM TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t2
                        WHERE   t2.SAP_ID = P_SAP_ID  
                            )
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t2
     WHERE  t2.SAP_ID = P_SAP_ID );
```

Why is it updating all and I want to update that one single row only?

Comment: You may also try to reproduce the behavior on a smaller example - closer to a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: Does it actually require to list all 54 columns to demonstrate the issue? Do you think that the issue is related to the number of columns in the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only condition you have on the `update` is

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t2
     WHERE  t2.SAP_ID = P_SAP_ID );
```

So you're telling Oracle that you want every row in `IPCOLO_BILLING_MASTER` updated if there is any row in `TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST` with a `SAP_ID` of `P_SAP_ID`.  Presumably, that is not what you actually want.

Since `IPCOLO_BILLING_MASTER` has a `SAP_ID`, my guess is that you want

```
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM TEMP_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST t2
     WHERE  t2.SAP_ID = P_SAP_ID 
       AND  t2.SAP_ID = t1.SAP_ID );
```

Presumably, you'd want similar logic in the `SELECT` statement you are using to get the values to update the table.

It may be clearer to re-write the `update` statement as a `merge` so that you don't have to duplicate this logic in two places.

If my guess is incorrect, please edit your question to include a reproducible test case.  You aren't very specific about what you do want to happen so we have to make a lot of guesses about what your data looks like and what you really want your `update` statement to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to test with `select count(*)` if rows exists and than update - use a single statement that will update some data or nothing. (Test and update approach can fail badly in a multiuser environment, with changes between the two statements).

There is no need to use `merge` if you *update* only as well. The elegant solution for your task is the [*updatable join view*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-C37E704C-AF40-42DA-85ED-372A62A74E58) feature.

Simple write a join of your *master* and *tmp* tables containing the join key, all columns to be updated and all columns with the new values.

```
select 
  m.sap_id,  /* join ID */
  m.LAST_UPDATED_DATE, m.LAST_UPDATED_BY, /* all columns to be updated */
 t.LAST_UPDATED_DATE TMP_LAST_UPDATED_DATE, t.LAST_UPDATED_BY TMP_LAST_UPDATED_BY /* new update values */
from master m
join tmp t
on m.sap_id = t.sap_id
where t.sap_id = P_SAP_ID

    SAP_ID LAST_UPDATED_DATE   LAST_ TMP_LAST_UPDATED_DA TMP_LAST_U
---------- ------------------- ----- ------------------- ----------
         1 27.12.2023 06:56:15 user1 28.12.2023 06:56:16 user2
```

Now pack the join in an `update` and `set` the values - thats it

```
update (
select 
  m.sap_id,  /* join ID */
  m.LAST_UPDATED_DATE, m.LAST_UPDATED_BY, /* all columns to be updated */
 t.LAST_UPDATED_DATE TMP_LAST_UPDATED_DATE, t.LAST_UPDATED_BY TMP_LAST_UPDATED_BY /* new update values */
from master m
join tmp t
on m.sap_id = t.sap_id
where t.sap_id = P_SAP_ID
)
set LAST_UPDATED_DATE  = TMP_LAST_UPDATED_DATE,
LAST_UPDATED_BY = TMP_LAST_UPDATED_BY
```

Note that you need to define a *unique index* on the *tmp* table join key to achieve a `key-preserved table` (otherwise you'll see `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`)